# What's the relative popularity of each of the stack overflow sites?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, statistics

And is there an easy way to find it? I'm most interested in number of threads/number of replies.

Comment: SO by a very large factor on most stats!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The network listing of sites at https://stackexchange.com/sites has some stats for each site and you can sort by each stat.

- questions
- answers
- % answered
- users, registered and unregistered
- visits/day, median over the last two weeks
- new 200+ rep users, in the last two weeks
- questions per day, averaged over the last two weeks
- new meta posts, in the last two weeks